# cx_Oracle: Using PL/SQL RECORD types as arguments to stored procedures

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm attempting to call AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG.CREATE_VENDOR from cx_Oracle (This is an Oracle R12 stored procedure) It requires an argument that is a predefined PL/SQL RECORD type. (AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG.R_VENDOR_REC_TYPE)

Here's my python code:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
obj = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.Object,                              
                              typename='AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG.R_VENDOR_REC_TYPE')
result = cursor.callproc('AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG.CREATE_VENDOR',
                         parameters=["1.0", "T", "T", 
                                     "fnd_api.g_valid_level_full", obj])
```

This results in the following exception:

`cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: object type not associated with bind variable`

What am I doing wrong? How do I call a stored procedure that requries a record type?

Comment: It sounds like the parameter doesn't like that it is an object. Have you tried cx_Oracle.STRING as the datatype?

Also, it could be because I am using Oracle 11g or because cx_Oracle 5.2.1, but I am getting an error saying that Object is not an attribute of Cx_Oracle. Maybe you meant to type OBJECT but didn't write it. If that is the case, please fix your example.

Comment: Thank you, @TylerChristian. I have answered my own question below. Unfortunately, I'm now getting `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_VENDOR'`, but that is a problem for a different SO question :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to get past this problem by using

```
type_obj = connection.gettype('AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG_R_VENDOR_RE')
obj = type_obj.newobject()
```

Note that the name is limited to 29 characters, and the period (.) has been replaced with underscore (_)

Comment: FYI from the Oracle 12.2 doc: "The maximum length of identifiers is increased to 128 bytes for most identifiers, up from 30 bytes in previous releases."